# Protobuf to Json convertor

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Map;
import com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FieldDescriptor;
import com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage;

public class ProtoToJson(){

//msg is any protobuf object 

public static String generateJsonFromMsg(GeneratedMessage msg) throws    IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException,  ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
   Map<FieldDescriptor,Object> allFields = msg.getAllFields();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(FieldDescriptor field: allFields.keySet()){
        sb.append("\"" + field.getName() +"\"");
        sb.append(":");
        boolean isRepeated = field.isRepeated();
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(msg.getClass().getName());
        try{
            String name = field.getName();
            if(isRepeated){
                name = name + "List";
            }
            Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod ("get"+ WordUtils.capitalize(name,new char [] {'_'}).replace("_", "") );
            Object value = method.invoke(msg);
            if(value instanceof GeneratedMessage){
                if(!isRepeated)
                     sb.append("{");
                sb.append(generateJsonFromMsg((GeneratedMessage)value));
                if(!isRepeated)
                     sb.append("}");
            }else {
                if(isRepeated){
                    sb.append("[");
                    List list = (List)value;
                    int size = list.size();
                    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                        if(list.get(i) instanceof GeneratedMessage)
                            sb.append("{").append(generateJsonFromMsg((GeneratedMessage)(list.get(i)))).append("}");
                        else 
                            sb.append(list.get(i));
                        if(i!=size-1){
                            sb.append(",");
                        }

                    }
                    sb.append("]");
                    //sb.append(value);
                } else
                    sb.append("\"" + value + "\"");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        sb.append(",");
    }
    //System.out.println("************************************************ "+sb.toString());
    return sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() -1).toString();
}
}
```

Comment: To make life easier for reviewers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does)

Comment: Also, have you heard about [the Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)? By looking at some of your code, it seems like you would have an easier time using a library that can do things for you.

Answer (score 7):

**Good**

- using of meaningful names
- sometimes using the method chaning of the `StringBuilder`

**Bad**

- `if` statements without `{}` brackets
- often using `StringBuilder.append` with adding values like `.append("x" + "y")`
- no spacing between the lines

By looking at this code

> ```
> List list = (List)value;
> int size = list.size();
> for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
>     if(list.get(i) instanceof GeneratedMessage)
>         sb.append("{").append(generateJsonFromMsg((GeneratedMessage)(list.get(i)))).append("}");
>     else 
>         sb.append(list.get(i));
>     if(i!=size-1){
>         sb.append(",");
>     }
>
> }
> ```

it is screaming to be extracted to a separate method. So let us start here.

```
private String generateJsonFromList(List list){
    int size = list.size();
    for(int i=0 ; i < size ; i++){
        Object item = list.get(i);

        if(item instanceof GeneratedMessage){
            sb.append("{")
              .append(generateJsonFromMsg((GeneratedMessage)(item)))
              .append("}");
        } else { 
            sb.append(item);
        }
        if(i!=size-1){
            sb.append(",");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

As we don't need to query `Class<?> c = Class.forName(msg.getClass().getName());` for each single `FieldDescriptor` in the loop, we will place it in front of the loop.

now the original method is looking like

```
public static String generateJsonFromMsg(GeneratedMessage msg) throws    IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException,  ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{

    Map<FieldDescriptor,Object> allFields = msg.getAllFields();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean isRepeated = false;
    Class<?> c = Class.forName(msg.getClass().getName());

    for(FieldDescriptor field: allFields.keySet()){
        String fieldName = field.getName();
        sb.append("\"")
          .append(fieldName)
          .append("\"")
          .append(":");

        isRepeated = field.isRepeated();

        if(isRepeated){
            fieldName = fieldName + "List";
        }
        try{
            Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod ("get"+ WordUtils.capitalize(fieldName ,new char [] {'_'}).replace("_", "") );
            Object value = method.invoke(msg);

            if(value instanceof GeneratedMessage){
                if(!isRepeated) {
                     sb.append("{");
                }

                sb.append(generateJsonFromMsg((GeneratedMessage)value));

                if(!isRepeated) {
                     sb.append("}");
                }
            } else {
                if(isRepeated){
                    sb.append("[");
                      .append(generateJsonFromList((List)value))
                      .append("]");
                } else {
                    sb.append("\"")
                      .append(value)
                      .append("\"");
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        sb.append(",");
    }

    return sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() -1).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a few best-practice issues which you are ignoring, and when combined they add up to a bit of a messy function.

First up, this code:

> ```
>             } else
>                 sb.append("\"" + value + "\"");
>         }
>     }catch(Exception e){
>         System.out.println(e);
>     }
> ```

Indentation is a very strong indicator of code logic blocks, and when the indentation goes awry, the logic in your code becomes harder to identify.

Now, that particular 6 line section of code, has a number of other problems......

- whitespace is an important part of code. You strip a lot of places where white-space is normally put. For example, `}catch(Exception e){` should be `} catch (Exception e) {`
- when you use a StringBuilder, you have the advantage of reduced memory 'churn' when compared with standard String concatenation..... so if you have a StringBuilder you should not be using String concatenation at all! Use the append method (and, for the double-quote, using a single-quoted version helps prevent the escape sequence....:

  > ```
  > sb.append("\"" + value + "\"");
  > ```

  should be:

  ```
  sb.append('"').append(value).append('"');
  ```
- 1-liner statement blocks should always be enclosed in `{...}` braces even though they are 1 line long. The code:

  > ```
  >     } else
  >         sb.append("\"" + value + "\"");
  > ```

  should be:

  ```
      } else {
          sb.append("\"" + value + "\"");
      }
  ```
- Exception handling is more than printing the exception, it is part of your diagnosis problem. You should at minimum also proint the data the at caused the exception. This is especially true inside loops, because you have no idea which iteration of the loop caused the problem. Not only is your exception useless for diagnosis, but it also traps exceptions that should nto be trapped.... what if the exception is an `SecurityException` then is it really OK to just keep going?

Talking about exceptions.... what I would like to see is a custom exception for the class, instead of the list of.... `IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException,  ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException`. Catching those exceptions where you do the reflection, and then wrapping them in a more descriptive exception that is then re-thrown, would allow you to have a much cleaner interface, and a simpler and more effective try/catch mechanism for your code.

When looking through HashMaps, you are looping through the keySet, and then, with the key, you are calling the map.get(key). This is inefficient because there is also the `entrySet()` which returns `Map.Entry` objects, which contain both values in one place. There's a good write-up here: [`entrySet()` vs. `keySet()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3870064/1305253).

Similarly, you have this loop:

> ```
>                 int size = list.size();
>                 for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
>                     if(list.get(i) instanceof GeneratedMessage)
>                         sb.append("{").append(generateJsonFromMsg((GeneratedMessage)(list.get(i)))).append("}");
>                     else 
>                         sb.append(list.get(i));
>                     if(i!=size-1){
>                         sb.append(",");
>                     }
>
>                 }
> ```

That loop could be used with the same idea as you have on the main loop, or there's an iterator version as well.... Consider this code:

```
for(Object val : list) {
    if(val instanceof GeneratedMessage) {
        sb.append("{").append(generateJsonFromMsg((GeneratedMessage)(list.get(i)))).append("}");
    } else {
        sb.append(val);
    }
    sb.append(", ");
}
// remove the last ', ' if needed.
if (!list.isEmpty()) {
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
}
```

Alternatively, you can also do:

```
for (Iterator<?> itr = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Object val = it.next();
    if(val instanceof GeneratedMessage) {
        sb.append("{").append(generateJsonFromMsg((GeneratedMessage)(list.get(i)))).append("}");
    } else {
        sb.append(val);
    }
    if (itr.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have thought about using the `sb.setLength()` but I haven't been sure if this is possible in java like it is in C#. Now I know.